# "Your child can/may/could/might do better with a different teacher"

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

1. Your child **can** do better with a different teacher.
2. Your child **may** do better with a different teacher.
3. Your child **could** do better with a different teacher.
4. Your child **might** do better with a different teacher.

Are they all correct/natural? (not asking about the differences between them)

Comment: Why are you asking this question.  Do you have a suspicion that some might not be correct.  What grammar rule do you think is involved here?#

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure about sentence (1). It seems to me a very certain thing to say. So "can" doesn't sound good. The rest seem to be fine.

Comment: I would agree with your interpretation.